# Why is the echo command returning this kind of result?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, echo

I made a typo today echoing an environment variable, and the result was unexpected. The environment variable contains a simple path.

```
$ export TEST_ENV_VAR=/path/to/some/project
$ echo $TEST_ENV_VAR
/path/to/some/project
```

My typo was two $$ instead instead of one. I would have expected `echo` to return something like `$/path/to/some/project` in this case.

```
$ echo $$TEST_ENV_VAR
11513TEST_ENV_VAR
```

Why does `echo` return this type of result?

Comment: `$$` is one of the special variables maintained by bash and contains the PID. For a complete list, see the bash man page and search for _Special Parameters_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `$$` returns the pid of the current process.

So the output displayed is the pid with `TEST_ENV_VAR` appended to it.

Answer (score 2):

`$$` is considered a special character.

> ($$) Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.

As you noticed, it returns a PID. This PID is the current shell you are using. If you use the command `ps aux | grep $$`  you would see something like this:

`1997   1    1997    19804  cons0    3293653 14:15:20 /usr/bin/bash`

Which means that in my case, I am using bash as shell.

[Source](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0024_0024)